# Bootstrap 5 floating label on top of the field

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, floating-labels

I want to put the floating label just like this:
[image]

The normal behaviour would be this but the input area is way to big for my purpose.
[image]

I don't have an idea how to set this up.
For Bootstrap 4 there was an extra framework but this won't work with V5.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did either of this solutions help you or work out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite the corresponding bootstrap 5 css class:

```
.form-floating>.form-control:focus~label,
.form-floating>.form-control:not(:placeholder-shown)~label,
.form-floating>.form-select~label {
  opacity: .65;
  transform: scale(.85) translateY(-.5rem) translateX(.15rem);
}
```

Set translateY(-.5rem) to -2rem or -20px or whatever fit's your layout.
You can also set background: white;

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `<fieldset>` and `<legend>` with your `<input>` inserted

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Password</legend>
    <input type="password">
</fieldset>
```

Then use CSS to set the padding / margin / border etc, as desired

More info: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp

Answer (score 0):

[Floating Labels](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/forms/floating-labels/) are a thing in Bootstrap 5.2.

Here is the way it would be done:

Wrap a pair of `<input class="form-control">` and `<label>` elements in `.form-floating` to enable floating labels with Bootstrap’s textual form fields. A placeholder is required on each `<input>` to leverage the  `:placeholder-shown` pseudo-element. Also note that the `<input>` must come first so we can utilize a sibling selector

```
<div class="form-floating mb-3">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com">
  <label for="floatingInput">Email address</label>
</div>
<div class="form-floating">
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password">
  <label for="floatingPassword">Password</label>
</div>
```